# Why does installing DBD::Pg fail in DynaLoader?

Tags: perl, postgresql

```
Error:  Can't load '/home/oracle/.cpan/build/DBD-Pg-2.16.1/blib/arch/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.so' for module DBD::Pg: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230.
```

Did anyone have similar error while instaling DBD::Pg perl module ? what can I do to fix it ?

Comment: Sounds like you don't have Postgres installed or DBD::Pg can't find the library.  btw... Could u change the tag to "postgresql"

Comment: I have postgre installed I've connected to the database.. I've set global variables HOME, LIB and one other I can't remeber the name .. right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go under perl to solve these dynamic linking problems. Use `strace program &> out`, and then grep for `libpq.so.5`. My guess is your `libpq.so.5` is in the wrong location, or your [DynaLoader](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/perl5.004_04/ext/DynaLoader/DynaLoader.pm) is misconfigured. Read the docs on `@dl_library_path`.

You can see what your search path is with this (the strace will also show it trying to find the .so by checking each directory):

```
perl -MDynaLoader -le'print for @DynaLoader::dl_library_path;'
```

Make sure your `libpq.5.so` falls in one of those. The `strace` will also show if the kernel is returning an error to DynaLoader that it is cloaking; moreover, it will certainly tell you everything DynaLoader knows.

Answer (score 0):

The libpq.so.5 file is missing, which indicates that you do not have the Postgresql client library installed.  On Ubuntu this file is provided by the libpq5 package.

Comment: I have it installed I can manually locate libpq.so and all permissions are right

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the path to the PostgreSQL library is in either ld.so.conf or in a file in ld.so.conf.d and re-run "sudo ldconf" (or sudo /sbin/ldconf).  That's taken care of this issue when I've encountered it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I know lots of people have answered your question but I thought I'd add one more thing. `Makefile.PL` locates the postgres libraries by executing `pg_config`. If this can't be found on your path, then you will find this sort of error. Interestingly though, it looks for the headers in the same way. Try running `pg_config` from your terminal and see what the output is. If it's not found in your path, locate it, add to your path and try to build `DBD::Pg` again