# Bugzilla throwing error DBD:Pg fail in DynaLoader?

Tags: perl, bugzilla, dbd

The following error shown when I access bugzilla:

```
pg' is not a valid choice for $db_driver in  localconfig: 
  Can't load 'lib/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.so' for module DBD::Pg: 
    libpq.so.5: failed to map segment from shared object: 
      Permission denied at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 230. 
  at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 47

Compilation failed in require at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 47.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Bugzilla/DB/Pg.pm line 47.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 952) line 3.
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?  It can [cause problems like this](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-users/2008-April/055576.html).

Comment: thanks pilcrow. the problem is with SELinux that link helped me to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Setting proper SELinux contexts and don't forget set environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH.
By setting this in httpd.conf fixed my problem like below:
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/var/www/html/bugzilla-4.2.1/lib/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBD/Pg/Pg.so".

Refer:
[stackoverflow discussion link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110435/why-does-installing-dbdpg-fail-in-dynaloader)
and [bugzilla google groups link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mozilla.support.bugzilla/libpq.so.5/mozilla.support.bugzilla/2TLRSh4f9HU/xrDAstodBmoJ)